# Json.org get parent

Tags: java, arrays, json, recursion

I am a novice in Java and I am looking for a way to get the parent of my JsonObject by using the library json.org (not json.org.simple)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide you method code in order to understand the code much better. Also edit the question for enhancing the clarity.

Comment: I simplify the question, because the method is very very long

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a solution (using `org.json.JSONObject`) that isn't horribly hacky ... and flawed.

I presume that what you are doing is traversing a JSONObject tree or path.  If so, a better approach (than trying to get the "parent" from the JSONObject) is to use a simple stack data structure to keep track of the node parents.